# Numerical Integration of two gaussians

Tags: integration, gaussian

I am trying to numerically integrate product of two gaussian functions $e^{-x^2/2}$ and $e^{-(x-2)^2/2}$ from -5 to 5. These two gaussian functions are two PDFs to denote the probability of two independent observables, which are independently normalized to 1. I know that the product of two gaussian PDFs must be a guassian centered at the midpoint of them. However, the resulting gaussian does not seem to account for the entire area that is present within the overlapping region. The procedure that I followed to integrate the product was as follows

1. Evaluate both the functions at $x$, and multiply them together to find the value of the integral at $x$.
2. The values are then summed to get the final integral.

I understand that I am missing something, but I am unable to figure out the mistake. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $$-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{(x-2)^2}2=-(x-1)^2-2.$$

Comment: If you are using numerical integration, there is need to rework the integrand.

Comment: Note you also probably want to use Gauss-Laguerre quadrature to integrate such functions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the pointers. I would look into the Gauss-Lauguerre quadrature. The resulting function should be ${-(x-1)}^2-1$ instead of ${-(x-1)}^2-2$.

Comment: @HEMANTHH: as far as I know, $\dfrac{2^2}2=2$.